# PySphere/pyvmomi how to retrieve the DNS and Routing settings of an EXSi host?

Tags: python, vcenter, pyvmomi

[image: det]Using PySphere library How could it possible to retrive the 'DNS and Routing' configuration of an EXSi host.

Here I need to retrieve the **Name** attribute under ***DNS and Routing*** -udm00esx04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [VMware pyvmomi page](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi), there is a link to the [vSphere WS SDK API documentation](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22/fa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc/doc/index.html).

While that documentation is not always intutitive, it is where I find answers to questions like this.

To answer your question, you need to obtain the host object, and then get the network properties (attributes) you want.  Assuming "esxi" is an object of type vim.HostSystem, the following will get the information you want:

```
 # dns name
 esxi.config.network.dnsConfig.hostName
 # domain name
 esxi.config.network.dnsConfig.domainName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyVim import connect
from pyVmomi import vmodl
from pyVmomi import vim


address = ''
username = ''
password =  ''

con = connect.SmartConnect(host=address, user=username, pwd=password)
content = con.RetrieveContent()

cv = content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(
            container=content.rootFolder, type=[vim.HostSystem], recursive=True)
for child in cv.view:
    print child.name, ": ", child.config.network.dnsConfig.hostName
```